# Integrating of von Neumann equation for density matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator, trace

Suppose we are given the Hamiltonian

$$H=f \frac{\text{Tr}\sigma_x \rho}{\text{Tr}\rho}\sigma_x,$$

where $\rho$ is the density matrix, and $\sigma_x$ is the Pauli matrix 
$$
\sigma_x=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$

and $f$ is a coupling constant. The time evolution of the density matrix is given by

$$\frac{d \rho}{dt}=if[\rho,\sigma_x]\frac{\text{Tr}\sigma_x \rho}{\text{Tr}\rho}.$$

How do I proceed from here? How do I integrate this equation?

Comment: It might be a good idea to write $\rho=\frac{1}{2}\left(I+\vec{u}\cdot\vec{\sigma}\right)$ where $\vec{\sigma}=\left(\sigma_{x},\sigma_{y},\sigma_{z}\right)$ and use the properties of the Pauli matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Your Hamiltonian does not make sense: The Hamiltonian cannot depend on the density matrix, but is a linear operator acting on the Hilbert space (the same space on which the density operator is acting).  Similarly, the von Neumann equation is a *linear* differential equation for $\rho$ (just as all of quantum mechanics is linear), which your equation isn't.

Otherwise, a correct von Neumann equation is a linear differential equation, and thus its integral is an exponential function.